# How can I get the mathematical model of the surface of a liquid rotating on a inclined surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, rotation

So I was playing around with my lab equipment, and I saw that if I let water rotate like this:
[image: An example of what I did]

It seems that the motion of the surface is periodic.How can I calculate an equation for the motion of the surface?

(The surface was about 5 degrees inclined and the angular velocity was about 4 rad/s)

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that there is an analytic solution to the motion of the water. The periodic effect would appear to be the result of resonance when the frequency of rotation is similar to the 'slop' frequency of the tank that can be observed if you gently oscillate a partially filled tank from side to side. You could confirm that by manually wobbling the stationary and level tank to find the frequency where it slops the most, and then trying to rotate it at about that speed to see if that maximized the periodic motion you are observing. If you played with tanks of varying dimensions you might find a linear relationship between maximal-slop frequency and maximal-rotational-slop-frequency.

The effect would probably be 'simplest' with a round tank - but even there I doubt that an exact analytic solution exists. But a rectangular tank will complicate the motion significantly, as there will be more than one slop frequency, and the corners of the tank will 'stir' the liquid in unpredictable ways.
[image]

Comment: Well, I took various photos of the surface and it seemed to be perfectly periodic. Perhaps we can consider gravity changing direction instead of an inclined rotation? It would be quite surprising if there is no analytic solution to such a fixed motion....

Comment: Yes, I expect it to be periodic (at least for moderate oscillations) - as will also be the case in a 'slopped' container without any rotation. So if the liquid has surface displacement D(x,t) at time t, and the period of the motion is T, then I would expect D(x,t) = D(x,t+nT). But I don't expect the surface displacement to be analytic in any way - in the sense that there will be no 'formula' that predicts D(x,0), i.e. the actual shape of the displacement.

Comment: In the lab, what I observed was with smaller velocities the surface seemed to be stable and parabolic, but when it comes to a certain velocity (probably a frecuency of resonance) the suface starts a periodic motion. I didn't try with higher velocities, as the water starts spilling out. But I expect at least a 'formula' for the frequency of resonance. And on the other hand, is it necessary to know D(x,0) to calculate an analytic solution? Isn't knowing D(x,t)=D(x+nT) and the pressure P(D,t)=P0 enough?

Comment: Yes, at low rotational velocities, well below the slop frequency, you should see a parabolic surface. Similarly, if you could spin fast enough - well above the slop frequency but not a simple multiple of it, you should also see a parabolic surface (although expect to spill a lot of water before you get there).  These stable sustems will be almost (but not exactly) steady state and he surface will nearly (but not exactly) be fitted by a parabola (thus nearly alalytic). But near resonance, I don't think you will find an analytic solution.

Comment: There are 'approximately' analytic solutions for water sloshing in a non-rotating container (see for example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1738573319301767 ) but they are not exact. For a rectangular (or even square) container there are multiple slop frequencies (for example in a square box slop parallel to an edge will have a different frequency to diagonal slop), Add rotation and wave reflection from sides non-perpendicularto the direction of wave motion wil further complicate things.

Comment: It would be possible, with significant computing effort, to produce a fairly accurate finite-elements solution to the fluid motion but I reiterate that an analytic solution for the motion, i.e displacement or depth of water calculated as a function of time, container dimensions, fluid depth and viscosity, tilt angle and rotational speed is most unlikely.